# Installing Epic (Eclipse Plugin) in Pulse Explorer

Tags: perl, eclipse, ide, plugins, pulse

I'm trying to install [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/) using the Pulse Explorer for Eclipse (as I'm rather fond of sharing profiles :). When I go to install the plugin under my account, I get asked for a login into `http://e-p-i-c.sf.net`.

However, the Epic's team documentation doesn't mention anything about a login.

Here's what I've done:

1. Gone into Pulse and created a new profile based on Eclipse Classic.
2. Navigated to Software, added the EPIC software site to list of public sites, and  chosen to install it.
3. Added Pulse item to profile.
4. Run the installer.

The error shows up while it's all downloading/installing. Login boxes start to appear for epic related components, and I don't have credentials to put in so all I can do is hit cancel. If I hit cancel, the process fails at the end with the generic error message: "*an unexpected error occurred preparing to install and/or launch the selected profile*".

Bundles that are failing to download are:

- `org.epic.debug`
- `org.epic.doc`
- `org.epic.lib`
- `org.epic.perleditor`
- `org.epic.regxp`
- `org.epic.source`

The component that's exploding is called:

`org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Credentials$LoginCancelledException`

I've had the same effect on Pulse 0.5.x and 0.6.x.

No clue where to go from here. Might contact the EPIC and Pulse teams and ask them, but thought that I'd get a better response from here. I'm somewhat sure I'm doing something wrong.

I have also posted this question in [Epic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/forums/forum/258688/topic/3579485), and [Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1203) forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem looks to be linked to the way Sourceforge lets you run concurrent connections, which Pulse is quite fond of.

If you want to install Epic inside a Pulse profile, it boils down to using the following update site URLs (depending on the version of EPIC you're going to want to run). Before you start, you might want to choose if you want to be on the Stable or Unstable branch:

- Stable has the update site url - http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/site.xml
- Unstable (6.x version) has the update site url - http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/site.xml

Just add this into your Pulse profile's 'Personal Sites' section. Here's what I did:

1. Inside the "My Profiles" section of Epic, select the profile you want to install Epic into.
2. When the pane loads, select the Software tab, and look at the column labeled 'Browse Software'. Click the hyperlink titled 'add site'.
3. Input one of the URL's above depending on what version of Epic IDE you want to run, and give it a name (e.g. Epic for Eclipse).
4. Right click on the packaged profile under "My Profiles", and click "Install and run".